# Pointers and Protected Memory in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, memory

I am working on a C# project to search the contents of windows event log files. It needs to be compatible with .evt and .evtx files.

I copied the code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15288/Parsing-event-log-evt-file that reads .evt files and in the case of some files (not all) when I run it, I get the error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.". This happens on the line:

```
*((int*)pd) = *((int*)ps);
```

The entire listing is:

```
namespace EventLogParser
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;

    // Show the progress 
    public delegate void ProgressHandler(int val, int max);

    // Send any message to UI
    public delegate void MessageHandler(string msg);

    // Parsed a new event.
    public delegate void NewEventFoundHandler(object[] items);

    internal class EventLogParser
    {
        //Constants for api call
        private const int NoError = 0;
        private const int ErrorInsufficientBuffer = 122;
        private readonly uint _offset;

        public EventLogParser()
        {
            TimeZoneInformation tzi;
            GetTimeZoneInformation(out tzi);
            _offset = (uint)(tzi.bias * 60) - (uint)(tzi.daylightBias * 60);
        }

        public event ProgressHandler OnProgress;
        public event MessageHandler OnAction;
        public event NewEventFoundHandler OnFoundRecord;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool LookupAccountSid(
            string lpSystemName,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] sid,
            StringBuilder lpName,
            ref uint cchName,
            StringBuilder referencedDomainName,
            ref uint cchReferencedDomainName,
            out SidNameUse peUse);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int GetTimeZoneInformation(out TimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);

        // Ctor

        // Parse the file
        public unsafe void Parse(string filename)
        {
            //try
            //{
            // Open the file
            using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                // Use BinaryReader to read the file
                using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    //Read the header of the file
                    var header = new byte[sizeof(EventLogHeader)];
                    br.Read(header, 0, header.Length);
                    var eventLogHeader = new EventLogHeader(header);
                    // Validate the file
                    if (!eventLogHeader.IsValid())
                    {
                        OnAction("Invalid file format.");
                        return;
                    }
                    //
                    var totalEvents = (int)(eventLogHeader.NextIndex - 1);
                    OnAction(String.Format("Found {0} events", totalEvents));
                    // Read the items
                    var cnt = 0;
                    var offset = eventLogHeader.FooterOffset;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var buff = ReadEntry(br, ref offset);
                        var e = ReadEntry(buff);
                        if (e == null)
                            continue;
                        cnt++;
                        var dt = GetTime(e.Rec.TimeGenerated);
                        OnFoundRecord(
                            new object[]
                                    {
                                        Enum.GetName(typeof (EventLogEntryType), e.Rec.EventType),
                                        dt.ToShortDateString(),
                                        dt.ToShortTimeString(),
                                        e.SourceName,
                                        e.Strings,
                                        e.Rec.EventCategory,
                                        e.Rec.EventID,
                                        e.UserSid,
                                        e.Computername
                                    });
                        if (cnt % 200 == 0) OnProgress(cnt, totalEvents);
                        if (offset == 48)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    OnAction(String.Format("Error Occurred! {0}", ex.Message));
            //}
        }

        // Read an event log record as byte[] from the file.
        private byte[] ReadEntry(BinaryReader br, ref uint endPoint)
        {
            br.BaseStream.Seek(endPoint - 4, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            if (br.BaseStream.Position >= br.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                return new byte[0];
            }

            var length = br.ReadUInt32();
            endPoint -= length;
            br.BaseStream.Seek(endPoint, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var buff = new byte[length];
            br.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            return buff;
        }

        // Parse the byte[] as an event log record
        private unsafe EventLogEntry ReadEntry(byte[] buff)
        {
            EventLogEntry entry;
            try
            {
                fixed (byte* ptr = buff)
                {
                    entry = new EventLogEntry { Rec = new EventLogRecord(buff) };
                    // Read SourceName
                    var start = (uint)sizeof(EventLogRecord);
                    // Get the Source Name
                    entry.SourceName = ReadString(ptr, ref start);
                    // Get the Computer Name
                    entry.Computername = ReadString(ptr, ref start);
                    // Get the User Name
                    var uname = new byte[entry.Rec.UserSidLength];
                    Copy(ptr, ref start, uname, uname.Length);
                    entry.UserSid = GetUserInfo(uname);
                    // read the strings
                    entry.Strings = ReadString(ptr, ref start, (int)(entry.Rec.DataOffset - entry.Rec.StringOffset) / 2);
                    // read the data
                    entry.Data = new byte[(int)entry.Rec.DataLength];
                    Copy(ptr, ref start, entry.Data, entry.Data.Length);
                    //
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                entry = null;
            }
            return entry;
        }

        // Read string from the byte[]
        private unsafe string ReadString(byte* ptr, ref uint start)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            ptr += start;
            while (true)
            {
                var temp = (char)*((ushort*)ptr);
                ptr += 2;
                start += 2;
                if (temp == '\0')
                    break;
                result.Append(temp);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }

        // Read the Description according to the length specified.
        private unsafe string ReadString(byte* ptr, ref uint start, int count)
        {
            var result = new StringBuilder(count);
            ptr += start;
            for (; count > 0; count--)
            {
                var temp = (char)*((ushort*)ptr);
                ptr += 2;
                start += 2;
                result.Append(temp);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }

        // Get the user name from SID
        private string GetUserInfo(byte[] buff)
        {
            var name = new StringBuilder();
            var cchName = (uint)name.Capacity;
            var referencedDomainName = new StringBuilder();
            var cchReferencedDomainName = (uint)referencedDomainName.Capacity;
            SidNameUse sidUse;

            int err = NoError;
            if (
                !LookupAccountSid(null, buff, name, ref cchName, referencedDomainName, ref cchReferencedDomainName,
                    out sidUse))
            {
                err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (err == ErrorInsufficientBuffer)
                {
                    name.EnsureCapacity((int)cchName);
                    referencedDomainName.EnsureCapacity((int)cchReferencedDomainName);
                    err = NoError;
                    if (
                        !LookupAccountSid(null, buff, name, ref cchName, referencedDomainName,
                            ref cchReferencedDomainName, out sidUse))
                        err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                }
            }
            if (err == 0)
                return String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", referencedDomainName, name);
            return @"N\A";
        }

        // copy the byte[]
        private unsafe void Copy(byte* pSrc, ref uint srcIndex, byte[] dst, int count)
        {
            if (count == 0)
                return;
            fixed (byte* pDst = dst)
            {
                var ps = pSrc;

                ps += srcIndex;
                byte* pd = pDst;

                // Loop over the count in blocks of 4 bytes, copying an
                // integer (4 bytes) at a time:
                for (int n = 0; n < count / 4; n++)
                {
                    *((int*)pd) = *((int*)ps);
                    pd += 4;
                    ps += 4;
                }

                // Complete the copy by moving any bytes that weren't
                // moved in blocks of 4:
                for (int n = 0; n < count % 4; n++)
                {
                    *pd = *ps;
                    pd++;
                    ps++;
                }

                srcIndex += (uint)count;
            }
        }

        // Convert to seconds to date time format
        private DateTime GetTime(uint time)
        {
            var output = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            time = time - _offset;
            output = output.AddSeconds(time);
            return output;
        }

        public class EventLogEntry
        {
            public string Computername;
            public byte[] Data;
            public string SourceName;
            public string Strings;
            public string UserSid;
            public EventLogRecord Rec;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public unsafe struct EventLogFooter
        {
            public uint FooterLength; // length 
            public uint Unknown0; // 0x11111111
            public uint Unknown1; // 0x22222222
            public uint Unknown2; // 0x33333333
            public uint Unknown3; // 0x44444444
            public uint Unknown4;
            public uint FooterOffset;
            public uint NextIndex;
            public uint Unknown7;
            public uint EndFooterLength;

            public EventLogFooter(byte[] data)
            {
                fixed (byte* pData = data)
                {
                    this = *(EventLogFooter*)pData;
                }
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public unsafe struct EventLogHeader
        {
            public uint HeaderLength; // length 
            public uint Signature; // signature
            public uint Unknown1;
            public uint Unknown2;
            public uint Unknown3;
            public uint FooterOffset;
            public uint NextIndex;
            public uint FileLength; // always wont give correct value
            public uint Unknown6;
            public uint Unknown7;
            public uint Unknown8;
            public uint EndHeaderLength;

            public EventLogHeader(byte[] data)
            {
                fixed (byte* pData = data)
                {
                    this = *(EventLogHeader*)pData;
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Checks whether the evt file is a valid one.
            /// </summary>
            public bool IsValid()
            {
                return HeaderLength == 0x00000030 &&
                       Signature == 0x654C664c &&
                       Unknown1 == 0x00000001 &&
                       Unknown2 == 0x00000001;
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public unsafe struct EventLogRecord
        {
            public uint Length;
            public uint Reserved;
            public uint RecordNumber;
            public uint TimeGenerated;
            public uint TimeWritten;
            public uint EventID;

            public ushort EventType;
            public ushort NumStrings;
            public ushort EventCategory;
            public ushort ReservedFlags;
            public uint ClosingRecordNumber;
            public uint StringOffset;
            public uint UserSidLength;
            public uint UserSidOffset;
            public uint DataLength;
            public uint DataOffset;

            public EventLogRecord(byte[] data)
            {
                fixed (byte* pData = data)
                {
                    this = *(EventLogRecord*)pData;
                }
            }
        }

        private enum SidNameUse
        {
            SidTypeUser = 1,
            SidTypeGroup,
            SidTypeDomain,
            SidTypeAlias,
            SidTypeWellKnownGroup,
            SidTypeDeletedAccount,
            SidTypeInvalid,
            SidTypeUnknown,
            SidTypeComputer
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct SystemTime
        {
            public readonly short year;
            public readonly short month;
            public readonly short dayOfWeek;
            public readonly short day;
            public readonly short hour;
            public readonly short minute;
            public readonly short second;
            public readonly short milliseconds;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private struct TimeZoneInformation
        {
            public readonly int bias;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public readonly string standardName;
            public readonly SystemTime standardDate;
            public readonly int standardBias;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public readonly string daylightName;
            public readonly SystemTime daylightDate;
            public readonly int daylightBias;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what could be done to fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tend to try and NOT use pointers in C#... it's rarely necessary.

Comment: +1 to Andrew. This doesn't look like a task where unsafe code is required.

Comment: Additionally, if you rewrite `Copy` and `ReadString` without pointers, you're likely to get a much more descriptive error message.

Comment: Sigh, codeproject.com code is chronically missing the "works only on my machine" disclaimer.  Undocumented file structures are pretty much guarantee to change on the next OS version.  And no, writing your own version of Marshal.Copy isn't required.

Comment: @Andrew How would you re-write this without pointers? :)

Comment: @Dan any suggestions of how to implement that?

Comment: `ReadString` should be fairly obvious; just change the `byte*` to a `byte[]` and subsequent pointer math to array indexing. `Copy` bears a strong resemblance to [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx)